# How do I add an Event Listener to a Dynamic Element?

Tags: dart, dartium

I have the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Description of Item 1</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-action="edit" data-item-id="1">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" data-action="delete" data-item-id="1">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>Description of Item 2</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-action="edit" data-item-id="2">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" data-action="delete" data-item-id="2">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table rows (`tr elements`) are added **dynamically**.

I wire up a click event to all `Edit` links like this:

```
void wireUpTableEvents() {
  var editLinks = queryAll('#order-items table tbody [data-action="edit"]');

  editLinks.forEach((element) {
    element.on.click.add((event){
      print(element.attributes['data-item-id']);
    });
  });
}
```

As said above, the table rows (`tr elements`) are added dynamically so the above code only works if I call `wireUpEvents` **after** I execute the method which adds the rows.

Does anyone know the syntax or adding a event listener to elements using `DART`'s `on.click.add()` when the elements are dynamcially added in the future?

I tried checking the DART documentation but the [**documentation on Event Listeners**](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_html/ElementEvents.html) is blank.

If I would be using jQuery I could be using something similar to:

```
$("#order-items table")on("click", "tbody [data-action="edit"]", function(){...})
```

...but I want to write my sample app only using DART.

**Edit**
Though `future` sounds great for callbacks it seemed slightly overkill for what I needed as there is no long running task in my scenario.

The closest I was able to get to attach my event listener to a static element but processing the click events of future sub-elements was this:

```
void wireUpTableEvents() {
    var tableBody = query('#order-items table tbody');

    // Attach Event Listener to the static tbody, which always exists.
    tableBody.on.click.add((event) {
        var clickedElement = event.srcElement;
        var itemId = clickedElement.attributes['data-item-id'];

        // Check if the clicked element was either one of the edit links or one of the delete links.
        switch (clickedElement.attributes['data-action']) {
        case 'edit':
            // Replace print with calling a method to process edit request for this item.
            print('processing edit click from item with id: $itemId');
            break;
        case 'delete':
            // Replace print with calling a method to process delete request for this item.
            print('processing delete click from item with id: $itemId');
            break;
        }
    });
}​
```

The above code can execute before any of the actual `tr` elements are loaded and still works after the `tr` elements are loaded at some unknown later stage.

I also found that it now covers any dynamically added row, pre-loaded ones as well as other dynamically added ones for new records etc.

Comment: I ended up going with the solution I added in the edit of the question. It allowed me to bind the event listener once to the table and processes any click event in any new row added dynamically at any stage by making use of event bubbling and the `event.srcElement` property.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the down-votes. By all means if this question doesn't show any research effort is unclear or useless feel free to do so and don't be afraid to let me know how to improve it! As currently the down-votes look random and nonsensical. The available documentation on the topic at the time of asking the question was none-existent and the link to it is now even completely dead. Feel free to post a comment with a link to the new documentation as I would love to be able to know of another solution to the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use Dart's Future object.  John Evans has a recent [post](http://phylotic.blogspot.com/2012/10/common-dart-scenarios-for-future.html) that gives an excellent overview.  I'll try to give a simple example:

Let's say I have a class called htmlInDart which I call as follows:

```dart
void main() {
  var htmlExample = new HtmlInDart().createStyles();
  htmlExample
      ..then((htmlExample) => htmlExample.buildPage())
      ..then((htmlExample) => htmlExample.addListeners());
}
```

The class might look something like this:

```dart
class htmlInDart {

  htmlInDart();

  Future<htmlInDart> createStyles() {
    final c = new Completer();
    // create some styles
    c.complete(this);
    return c.future;
  }

  Future<htmlInDart> buildPage() {
    final c = new Completer();
    // build the page
    c.complete(this);
    return c.future;
  }

  Future<htmlInDart> addListeners() {
    final c = new Completer();
    // add some listeners
    c.complete(this);
    return c.future;
  }
```

Hopefully this gives you some idea of how to implement it for your case.

Comment: This looks promising. I will have a read over the post and answer properly tonight. I remember coming across `future` in the available documentation before but could not make head or taill of it at the time. I will reply with an update tonight after reading through it and having a play around in my app.

Comment: Seth Ladd also did a [post](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/03/using-futures-in-dart-for-better-async.html) on using futures in Dart that may help.

Comment: I was able to implement it with `future`. It seems though that `future` is more for long-running tasks. I suppose I was looking more for attaching an event listener to a higher level element targeting some future sub-elements using the existing `on.click.add` somehow, similar to `on()` with delegation in jQuery. However, as it doesn't seem to be available in DART, using a callback using `future` looks like the closest thing that works instead. In my specific example I might stick with calling wire-up later but `future` is defiantly something I will need later on for other tasks.

Comment: I also found another solution after playing around with the code for a little longer, which was semantically closer to what I was looking for. I only added it as an edit to my original question though as I'm not sure if this is something acceptable to do in DART or not (it does work though). Another bonus I found doing it like that was that if I keep adding new rows through other actions, I don't need to constantly add new event listeners to each new row and if the table is re-loaded I don't need to worry about removing/re-adding event listeners to prevent duplicate event listeners.

Comment: I'm glad you came up with a great solution.  Futures do seem to be a bit much for your application.  Thank you for accepting this answer anyway.

Comment: Your answer seemed the most appropriate using DART features, that's why I think it was a good answer. If the solution I used is actually something I should be doing in DART I'm not sure. Thanks again for your time and the links. Both posts you linked, as well as the DART documentation on [asynchronous programming](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/library-tour/#asynchronous-programming) were very interesting reads.

Comment: You could also try asking about your solution on Dart's [forum](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/misc).  I get a lot of great information about Dart on that forum as well as here.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't add the callback when you are adding the rows in the first place? Something like:

```
void addRow(TableElement table, ...) {
    TableRowElement item = new TableRowElement();

    ...

    table.nodes.add(item);
    item.on.click.add((callback) { });
}
```

Comment: Thansk for the reply. I could do that but don't want to make adding a row necessarily responsible for wiring up events. I rather keep thos responsibilities separate. In the moment I do that by simply calling addRows followed by wireUpEvents. I just wondered what the DART way of dealing with the `dynamic element` scenario was assuming there is one. I'm looking into `Future` later tonight to see if that addresses that scenario.